# Am I Correctly Building My Firebase Data Structure?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to figure out my firebase db structure and have 3 questions.

1-Is the way I have it laid out below good/efficient? I tried to keep it as shallow as possible based on what I've read about fb.

2-If I have a set of data, "portal_coordinates", that gets copied over to another parent once a criteria has been met ("all" vs. "completed"), would the setup under "portal_coordinates" be ideal? Or would a setup similar to "awards" be better?

3-Is it possible to have multiple fb dbs for 1 app? Using my example below, can I put "portal_coordinates_ALL" on a separate db? I'm guessing no and that I should just house all my info under 1 db.

```
{
"users": {
    "user01": {
        "email": "user01@gmail.com"
    },
    "user02": {
        "email": "user02@gmail.com"
    }
}
// best to list all awards regardless of true or false?
"awards": {
    "user01": {
        "first_time": true,
        "five_in_a_row": true,
        "share_with_friend": false,
        "create_your_own": false
    },
    "user02": {
        "first_time": false,
        "five_in_a_row": false,
        "share_with_friend": false,
        "create_your_own": false
    },
}
// or should it be broken up similarly to below, 'completed' and 'all'?
"portal_coordinates_COMPLETED": {
    "user01": {
        "california": {
            "san_francisco": {
                "location02": {
                    "latitude": "37.831502",
                    "longitude": "-122.292161"
                }
            }
            "los_angeles": {
                "location01": {
                    "latitude": "33.941544",
                    "longitude": "-118.408198"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
"portal_coordinates_ALL": {
    // do we want to be this detailed?
    "california": {
        "los_angeles": {
            "location01": {
                "latitude": "33.941544",
                "longitude": "-118.408198"
            },
            "location02": {
                "latitude": "34.069045",
                "longitude": "-118.445294"  
            }
        }
        "san_francisco": {
            "location01": {
                "latitude": "37.784440",
                "longitude": "-122.408002"
            }
            "location02": {
                "latitude": "37.831502",
                "longitude": "-122.292161"
            }
        }
    }
}
// 'images' don't have any 'users' relationship but does have app relationship, place in database?
"images": {
    "image01": "http://www.petwave.com/~/media/Images/Center/Care-and-Nutrition/Cat/Kittensv2/Kitten-3.ashx"
    "image02": "http://www.puppyoung.com/wp-content/uploads/sh/shiba-shiba-inu-puppies-breed.jpg"   
}
```

}